# Efficient Directory Structure

Tags: php, algorithm, directory

What would be the best directory structure for a massive amount of file.
Considering i have more than 20 million of files using number_id as file names (ex. 13842985.xml).

if would go with something like

```
filename : 13842985.xml
directory :  1/3/8/13842985.xml
```

How can i do this properly wherein all files are scattered evenly on each directories and subdirectories.

Comment: I would just hash the filename and use the last two or three digits to split it into buckets

Comment: Scatter them all around and index them in a database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your method slightly to this instead:

```
filename  : 13842985.xml
directory : 842/985/13842985.xml    # use the 6 last to create the directory name
```

I am assuming the filenames are somewhat random. This scheme will create 1000 top folders, each containing 1000 subfolders. By starting from the last digits instead of the first, you will be protected against long filenames:

```
filename  : 138429851234.xml
directory : 851/234/138429851234.xml
```

Hope this helps!

Edit: By hashing the filename first and using this number instead, you'll avoid degenerate cases (for example, varying only in the beginning).

Comment: i think this one is good. however filenames are treated like counter so they would start from 1.xml, 2.xml ... 1000.xml ..... n.xml up to number of files which would likely be around 11 million or more. would this technique be appropriate?

Comment: The advisability of this technique depends on your filesystem.  Some get slow if they have lots of files in them, others don't.  There is no need to do this if it doesn't help.

Comment: @Mao: Sure I think this technique would work fine for you. You don't need to hash the filename either, in your case. The first 1000 files (1-1000) would go into the same folder, the next 1000 (1001-2000) would go into the next folder, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You could create the directory structure like a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).

Answer (score 0):

Do some benchmarking to figure out where the tradeoff between having to scan through multiple directorie becomes cheaper than having to scan through "many" files in a single directory.

At some point the file system overhead of opening/scanning/security-checking/etc... on each directory layer you add will be higher than the savings from having to parse the directory to find the single file you want. That's the level you'd do your split/layering cutoff.